# Update query in stored procedure taking a lot of time

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, query-optimization, query-performance, sqlperformance

This is for SQL Server 2012. I have been asked to optimize a stored procedure that is used for calculating billing amount for various invoices. 
This is a huge stored procedure with a lot of insert, update and delete queries with joins on multiple tables. 
The stored procedure is getting stuck on this particular update query for 8-9 hours. The query is updating around 400000 records.

At the time of stored procedure execution, there is no other connection with the database except the one running the stored procedure.

`The query is`

```
UPDATE D

SET Amount=CASE WHEN D.Container='PCS' AND DP.AmountPerStop =0 THEN DP1.Amount*ISNULL(ISNULL(M2.MPDFactor, M.MPDFactor), 1) ELSE DP1.Amount+DP.Amount*(DeliveryQty-1) END,
    InvoiceID=I.InvoiceID,
    MPDFactor=CASE WHEN D.Container='PCS' AND DP.AmountPerStop =0 THEN ISNULL(M2.MPDFactor, M.MPDFactor) ELSE NULL END,
    PickupAmountCap = DP.PickupAmountCap

FROM dbo.tDeliveries D
   JOIN tDeliveryPrices DP ON DP.ProductGroupCode=D.ProductGroupCode AND DP.Container=D.Container AND DP.Zone=D.Zone
   JOIN tVendorAgreements A ON A.DIP=D.DIP AND DP.VendorAgreementID=A.VendorAgreementID
   JOIN tDeliveryPrices DP1 ON DP1.ProductGroupCode=D.ProductGroupCode AND DP1.Container=D.Container AND DP1.Zone=D.Zone AND DP1.VendorAgreementID=A.VendorAgreementID
   JOIN tDIP DIP ON D.Dip=DIP.Dip
   JOIN tInvoices I ON A.VendorAgreementID=I.VendorAgreementID
   JOIN @tDailyInvoicePeriodForDIP IP ON IP.DIP = DIP.DIP
   LEFT JOIN tMPDFactors M ON M.DIPArea=DIP.DipArea AND M.ProductGroupCode=D.ProductGroupCode AND D.DeliveryQty BETWEEN M.StartQty AND M.EndQty        
   LEFT JOIN tMPDFactors M2 ON M2.DIP=DIP.Dip AND M2.ProductGroupCode=D.ProductGroupCode AND D.DeliveryQty BETWEEN M2.StartQty AND M2.EndQty           

WHERE D.InvoiceID IS NULL AND
      I.InvoicePeriod= @Period AND
      I.InvoiceLockedDate IS NULL AND
      DP1.StartQty=1 AND
      (DeliveryQty BETWEEN DP.StartQty AND DP.EndQty OR D.Container='PCS') AND 
      D.Event_Type = 'I' AND
      @Period BETWEEN A.ValidFromDate AND A.ValidUntilDate
```

As far as the end result is concerned, the query is working fine. It is just taking so much time. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just the query isn't going to tell us much here. We're really going to need the query plan ([Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)), and likely the DDL of the indexes and tables. Start with the Query Plan, and then we can see what DDL we'll need.

Comment: Also, please update the question to include the version of SQL Server are you using. In older versions table variables, like @tDailyInvoicePeriodForDIP, can get bad row estimates which will cause the query planner to do very silly things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the recompile option for the stored procedure?  If your stored procedure generated a query plan using a very small dataset, your plan may force the procedure to walk very large tables because the original query plan determined that walking the table was the most efficient method to either gather or update data.  This may not complete resolve your issue but it is another option.  Also, the suggestion is a great place to start to determine inefficient steps.